# Changing image src with jQuery

Tags: jquery, dom, image

I'm replacing some code in an old application, and instead of getting the node by it's id I get it by it's class. Because there isn't a good way to get a node by it's class in native JS I do it with jQuery, however the new code doesn't change the img src.

Is there an obvious reason?

Old code:

```
var gamearea = document.getElementById('gamearea')
var images = gamearea.getElementsByTagName('img');
images[place] = "pics/" + id + ".png";
```

New code:

```
$('.gamearea').children('img').eq(place).src = "pics/" + id + ".png";
```

Comment: There are "good" ways to get elements by their `className` (without selectors). You're just being myopic. As David said, please post your HTML so a better solution can be posted.

Comment: @Matt: while it's true that there are good ways, such as `document.getElementsByClassName()`, jQuery *does* make it easier cross-browser,compensating for OR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.eq()` returns a jQuery object.  If you want to use the `.src` property directly, you need a DOM element (not a jQuery object) for which you would use `.get()` instead of `.eq()` like this:

```
$('.gamearea').find('img').get(place).src = "pics/" + id + ".png";
```

I also switched to `.find()` instead of `.children()` to be more equivalent to `.getElementsByTagName()` that you had in the original version and since you didn't show us your HTML, it seems a safer assumption.

Answer (score 3):

```
function updateGameAreaImages(id, place) {
    var gameareas = toArray(document.getElementsByClassName('gamearea'));
    gameareas.forEach(updateImages);

    function updateImages(elem) {
        var images = elem.getElementsByTagName("img");
        images[place].src = "pics/" + id + ".png";
    }
}

function toArray(obj) {
    var arr = [];
    for (var i = 0, len = obj.length; i < len; i++) {
        arr[i] = obj[i];
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$('.gamearea').children('img').eq(place)[0].src = "pics/" + id + ".png";
```

or:

```
$('.gamearea').children('img').eq(place).attr("src", "pics/" + id + ".png");
```

`$('.gamearea').children('img').eq(place)` returns a jQuery "array" of elements, you can’t access DOM attributes directly on this object. You need to either pull the DOM element by using `[0]` (the first element) or use a method from the jQuery api, in this case [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).

Also, you might mean to use `$('#gamearea')` instead of `$('.gamearea')` if you are replacing `getElementById('gamearea');`

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old answer, but surely this is a better way...

```
$('.gamearea').children('img').attr("src", "pics/" + id + ".png");
```